# I am using Ubuntu to run a java file

Tags: java, ubuntu

After  I compile the helloworld.java I tired to run helloworld.java using

java helloworld .java

I noticed there is a space between helloworld and period. What is the reason for this spacing.

Comment: maybe your filename contains the space?

Comment: Please post you code to see if you are using a package

Comment: `java helloworld.java` isn't valid itself, forget the space which you put in between.

Comment: `.java` ends up as the zeroth entry in the string array passed to your main method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type:

```
java helloworld
```

But a class normally begins with an uppercase character in Java (it's a convention not a rule).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a space while compiling/running a java program on an Ubuntu terminal.
For compiling, you use:
javac helloworld
For running:
java helloworld

Make sure you are in the same directory as the file (on the terminal).
As a matter of fact, if you try java helloworld .java, it should give you an error.
Do send me a screenshot of your terminal showing exactly what happens when you type that.